# "The man with short black hair" vs. "He with short black hair"

Tags: grammar

> **The man with short black hair** is giving a presentation.
>   **He with short black hair** is giving a presentation.

Is it okay to say "He with ~"? I've never heard that "He with ~"

Comment: In a normal, non-archaic style, only the first is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only using the pronoun is considered  very *stylistic* way of speaking.

> **He** with **the** short black hair.
>   **She** who must be obeyed.

there is a certain heaviness and gravity when this construction is used, but it will be understood.

The construction of your first sentence is more usual

> *The man* with short black hair.
>   *Your wife* who must be obeyed.